# AWS ubuntu instance scp fail

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to copy local files to aws, and I used following command but it doesn't work, can anyone help? etl is the folder I created and want to put all files in

```
scp -i C:/Users/Bonnie/Downloads/afinn.txt ubuntu@ec2-54-69-164-253.us-west-       2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/etl
```

thanks!

Comment: usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2

Comment: just like this, I am wondering if the local path is not appropriate, I am using windows, would that be a problem?

Comment: Can you fix your command? I see blanks in hostname. Can you access the local path with other commands (like type)?

Comment: Oops. I just noticed you are either not specifying the private key file or not specifying the files to be copied. `-i` option expects a private key file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan, you are not passing the files you intend to copy to the remote server.

scp -i key filestocopy user@server:/folder/destination/

Comment: Thanks! one quick question, say if my file is at c:\aa.txt, what should I write in "filestocopy" part?

Comment: Yes. You can also use a pattern such as c:\*.txt

Comment: Not really, it seems x:\**\ kind of path cant be recognized. I used WINSCP and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. It is c:\aa.txt. As Linux is different from Windows, if it doesn't work, please try c:/aa.txt or simply aa.txt.